# Change column collation and set it to not null in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to change the table column collation and set the column to not null using the following script.

```
alter table test  
alter column salary varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS

alter table test  
alter column salary varchar(20) not null
```

SQL Server is allowing only one change... either it changes collation or not null. Column cannot have both collation and not null.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
create table test (
    salary varchar(10) collate Latin1_General_CI_AI null
)
go  
alter table test  
alter column salary varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS not null
```

I would, however, query whether any form of text was the correct data type for a column called `salary`.

Answer (score 0):

The following states the opposite. And I just tested in a local environment. And I had no problem altering the collation and setting not null at the same time.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx